# How do I check if the date I input matches the time stamp a few text files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

Using bash I input my year month and day and need to check if a text file contains that particular date and if so I need to return the text file name.

Eg:

```
ThreadNum: 309264
Subject: Re: math
To: aaaa1425@aol.com (aaa)
From: Doctor Douglas
TimeStamp: 03/08/2004 at 13:58:57
Sent: yes
```

If my input matches the the time stamp I need to print out the file name. How do I match the time stamp using bash ?

Comment: errr `grep -l date files` ?

Comment: `grep -lIR 'TimeStamp: 03/08/2004' /directory/with/files/`

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`egrep -l 'TimeStamp: 03/08/2004' file`

you can specify as many files as you want or just use `*` insted of `file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` for that:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -l 'TimeStamp: 03/08/2004' {} \;
```

- `-type f` tells `find` to look for only for files.
- `-exec grep -l` tells `find` to call upon the `grep` utility. The `-l` argument tells `grep` to search a file only until the given search string, in this case `TimeStamp: 03/08/2004` is found. If a match is found, the pathname of the file is printed to stdout.

Depending on the size of the directory, the number of files and the amount of data those files contain, this may take a little time to complete. If all of the files to be searched are contained in a single directory then the time will be significantly reduced.

For example, searching through every file in the `$HOME` folder will take much longer than it would if the search is narrowed down to `$HOME/Documents/Text_Files`.